# Numerical integration does not converge

Tags: numerical-integration, convergence

```
Integrand[f_,z_]:=(7768.33 (1 + z)^1.7)/(Sqrt[
 0.69 + 0.31 (1 + z)^3] (1 + 
   0.00257378 (1 + z)^5.6) (9.60488 f^2 (1 + z)^2 + (8.5146*10^6 - 
     2.40122 f^2 (1 + z)^2)^2))
```

I am integrating numerically the Integrand above for z ranging from 0 to 8. I then multiply this with some constant factor and plot for f from 0 to 4000. It is clear from the plot (see below) that there are errors in the numerical integration.

[image]

Indeed, when I ask for the calculated value at some f in the error area (eg f=1000), I get the following error message.

[image]

I am new to Mathematica, I would appreciate some help in getting rid of the errors.

Comment: Can you look at what happens when you replace the `5.6` and `1.7` exponents with `28/5` and `17/10`?

Answer (score 4):

Obviously you have numerical errors. Therefore, you need another method, e.g. "LocalAdaptive" that will adapt the step size to local needs.

```
Integrand[f_, 
  z_] := (7768.33 (1 + z)^1.7)/(Sqrt[
     0.69 + 0.31 (1 + z)^3] (1 + 
      0.00257378 (1 + z)^5.6) (9.60488 f^2 (1 + z)^2 + (8.5146*10^6 - 
         2.40122 f^2 (1 + z)^2)^2))
Plot[NIntegrate[Integrand[f, z], {z, 0, 8}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"], {f, 0, 3000}]
```

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!